# How do I enter disk location on Ubuntu 18 in Nautilus / Files?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I switched from ubuntu 14 to ubuntu 18 and I am puzzled big time how to do simple functions:

For example on ubuntu 14 I had chance to open dialog and enter disk path. I have no idea how to do this with new Ubuntu/Nautilus.

I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 and Files 3.26.4 ...

How it looks to me Nautilus got cut from left to right and from up to down. I cannot find a lot of functions that I was able to do earlier. Some things are made really user friendly and to some degree better but at some points being unable to do things gets really annoying to the point that I think of going back to previous version of OS.

I just tried to find it in Help - no mention what so ever about being able to enter disk location (path).

p.s. when I use 'user friendly' the question is - to which kind of user it is user friendly? - for me user friendly means I can quickly do all functions I need.

Comment: I think `Ctrl+l` is what you need?

Comment: Yes that works thanks. But with the mouse? From all these nice new menu's?

Comment: I installed nautilus (I use linux mint) and no, I can't find any way to do this within the GUI. Give Nemo a try, it's my defacto file browser.

Comment: Already have Mint on double boot. Will explore. But thank you for confirming my findings. Function is there but not user friendly.